# Not getting prompt after executing python script from bash

Tags: python, linux

I am executing a python script from bash script as follows
"python -O myscript.pyo &"

After launching the python script I need to press "enter" manually to get prompt.

Is there a way to avoid this manual intervention.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

pipe a blank input to it:

```
echo "" | python -O myscript.pyo
```

you might want to create a bash alias to save keyhits: `alias run_myscript="echo '' | python -O myscript.pyo"`

Comment: Just to mention, I am running the python script in background by appending & to it. I tried what you mentioned, but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

placing wait after the line to run the process in background seems to work.

Source:
http://www.iitk.ac.in/LDP/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#WAITHANG

Example given:

## !/bin/bash

## test.sh

ls -l &
echo "Done."
wait

Many thanks